# Acrylic bathtub small crack

Tags: repair, bathtub, acrylic

I just found a small crack, about 1 inch, on my acrylic bathtub floor. The tub is a Kohler Devonshire 1357 about 14 years old. Tub looks almost new, crack looks superficial just the acrylic surface. I can’t see it underneath because it’s on the opposite side of my access but the tub has what I believe is a fiberglass backing and I can’t imagine it went through that.

Is this something I should repair with a kit they sell at home improvement store or will the crack expand in the near future and should just look for new tub? Will the repair look descent, it’s a very small crack and doesn’t seem to flex.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. You should [take our tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you will know how this site operates with upvotes for helpful information and checks for accepted answers.

Comment: "I can’t see it underneath because it’s on the opposite side of my access" Can you see it with a mirror on a stick or a phone with a selfie stick?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you checked with Kohler on this but they have a lifetime warranty on acrylic/plastic tub surfaces if you are the original owner. Depending on the nature/cause of the damage you might be able to get it covered despite it's age. If they don't cover it they may still be able to help you with advice on a method of repair. Give it a shot.
Here's a link: https://www.us.kohler.com/webassets/kpna/catalog/pdf/en/1353553-12.pdf

Comment: Unfortunately I’m not the original owner, put in about 2 years before me. I think it just happened from my heel when I was standing in the tub, don’t believe anything fell. Heard a cracking sound but didn’t notice anything until about 2 days later when cleaning.

Comment: If you buy repair kits, check for expiry date.

Comment: Nick don't worry any use the wrong set for the tub anyway.  They used to use sand but once deflcted it stayed defective.  Then they tried concrete and for most it would work but if most actually read the manual is probably gonna say use,  Plaster o Paris.